# Is there a way to set a static class as a value to a static variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class for my app that controls some properties. I am trying to achieve something similar to this (code does not work):

```
class App {
   static final AppColors colors = AppColors;
   static final AppVariables variables = AppVariables;
}
```

Quick example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
App.colors.accent OR App.variables.storage
```

`AppColors` and `AppVariables` are abstract class with only static variables. The code above does not work and the normal way is to just get an instance of each class with:

```
static final AppColors colors = AppColors();
```

but the problem is then the static variables and methods in my `AppColors` class wont work, obviously.

Question is: **How do I point to a class with a variable (without instantiating it)?**

Comment: I think you dont need to intialize, you just need to use App.AppColors to set wherever you require.

Comment: Each of the classes are in seperate files, and don't extend from eachother. @AnkitTale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Just remove static from all variables** from `AppColors` and `Appvariables` classes. Since you initialize those classes in a static variable, you can call their non-static variables at once. Let me show you an example.

```
class App {
   static final AppColors colors = AppColors();
}

class AppColors{
  final int color1 = 3;
}
```

You can call like this.

```
void main() {
  print("VALUE ${App.colors.color1}");
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

First off: you can't. A static member belongs to the class itself, not an object of the class. Thus, `colors` will never have an `accent` and `variables` will never have a `storage` (with your current design). You can still do `AppColors.accent` or `AppVariables.storage`, or make the fields of `AppColors` and `AppVariables` non-static so that you can do `colors.accent` and `variables.storage`.

Second off: this looks like you are trying to do some sort of state management with this approach. Whenever you change one of those values, the application will not react to that state change. I'd recommend taking a look at [`get_it`](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) or [`riverpod`](https://riverpod.dev) to correctly handle state management.

Edit: you could also use the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to do this, but I would highly recommend taking a look at riverpod or get_it first.